# input tag inside p tag using jquery

Tags: html, css, inline

```
$Option = "<p>6 &lt; x &lt; 8</p>"  //For demo I have assigned directly, in reality the value will come from MySQL database.
```

I want to display this value something like:

[image: expected result]

But I am getting it like:

[image: reallity result]

I know the reason why it is like that because the input tag is out of paragraph tag.

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="A"><?php echo $Option; ?>
```

What can I do so that the radio button is inside paragraph tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` elements are `block` elements by default. You can make them `inline` elements by setting the `display` property value to `inline`:

```
$Option = '<p style="display:inline">6 &lt; x &lt; 8</p>';
```

**Update:** If you are not able to change the value of the variable then you can try using external or internal CSS:

```
input[type=radio] + p{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: As said in the code commentary, it is not possible for me to edit all the options in the database.